# How to make a POJO "A" with POJO "B" for Gson but just use one variable of "B" for "A"

Tags: java, json, gson

First of all I am sorry for the complicated title, I could not find a better way to explain my problem, but here I'll do so:

Here are my two POJOs:

POJO 1:

```
public class Station {

private int id;
private String name;
private ArrayList<String> lines;

public Station(int id, String name, ArrayList<String> lines) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.lines = lines;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public ArrayList<String> getLines() {
    return lines;
}

}
```

POJO 2:

```
public class Connection {

private Station origin;
private Station destination;
private double time;

public Connection(Station origin, Station destination, double time) {
    this.origin = origin;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.time = time;
}

public int getOrigin() {
    return origin.getId();
}

public int getDestination() {
    return destination.getId();
}

public double getTime() {
    return time;
}

}
```

As you can see, I am integrating the "Station" POJO into the "Connection" POJO.
If I now want to convert an object of Connection to a JSON String, it will obviously format the two stations "origin" and "destination" as well. But here's the problem: I just want the "origin" and "destination" to be represented by its code, not the full data such as "name" or "lines".

How can I make GSON ignore these variables?

Kenta1561

Comment: There is the [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) pattern that deals with what you're asking: just create a `ConnectionDto` with strings rather than `Station`s, or special `StationDto` with just a single field -- and just convert `Connection` to it accordingly. This would work with any serializing library. Otherwise you need a custom serializer for Gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't ignore those values in the serialization.

There's nothing really wrong with having them there.

You instead should parse out the only the necessary data in your database or UI.

If you did only want the station id and name in a Connection, then you can have an abstract Connection class with only the id and name fields